Can there be a true Void, Vacuum in nature?
A true vacuum as opposed to a false vacuum doesn't seem plausible.
I mean from a true vacuum can anything pop into existence?
I mean if it were a true vacuum then nothing will pop into existence from it right?
So one conclusion is that there may be an infinite number of false vacuums.
I am trying to discern if it's logical possible to have a true void in space.
Obviously our existence proves that a true void is impossible.
What do you think?

Do you mean the kind of vacuum where you have a region of space with no gas, or the kind where a quantum field is in its lowest possible energy state? Because "true void in space" suggests the first, but the term "true vacuum" is about the second, and the two kinds aren't especially related. (Either way, this is probably a physics question, not a philosophical one.)

I'm voting to close because I think this is, as it stands, a physics question.

There is a flaw in your argument. A true vacuum is an absence of anything. If something popped into that vacuum it does not negate the definition of a vacuum. If something popped into it, that vacuum has just become not a vacuum.

This is the topic of an ancient Taoist riddle : "Starlight asked Non-entity [whose appearance was that of a deep void] ... do you exist? or do you not exist?" The answer is that the void 'exists' only in Starlight's mind.

Under the standard model, fields permeate space. This is a field quantum theory and there is always the possibility of a particle being detected in any given region.

The (true) vacuum is defined as the ground state of the universe, i.e. the state of lowest energy. The energy of the vacuum is not necessarily zero.
Due to vacuum fluctuations the vacuum may spontaneously create particles, which later annihilate again. For an introduction, notably from the viewpoint of quantum mechanics (QM) see Vacuum.
Note also the analogy from the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator in QM: The lowest state does not have zero energy. It's value can be easily calculated.

But in that case the physical vacuum isn't truly a vacuum as an absence of anything.

@MathematicalPhysicist One may say that the definition of a vacuum as absence of anything is an empty definition: A vacuum in this sense does not exist. - Instead the physical vacuum of QM exists as the state of lowest energy. That's a useful concept, see the quantum fluctuations. - Lessons learned: Not every concept originating from natural philosophy is a useful concept. One should always check each candidate against the state of art in science.

@MathematicalPhysicist. Science proposes a stable amount of energy in the universe as absolute and unchanging. The universe could not have the lowest state of energy because that is in contradiction to the proposition of the body that is telling you that it can have a lowest state. Beware of snake oil salesmen.
